# A = b || "foo"; complains that 'b' is undefined and does not assign a to "foo". What am I missing?

Tags: javascript

In my JavaScript code, and in Chrome dev tools I write:

```
a = b || "foo";
```

And get this error:

```
ReferenceError: b is not defined
```

And a is not set to "foo". I know this is a valid pattern in JavaScript. What am I missing?

Comment: "Have I not had enough coffee?" How can we know... Do you have such feeling? Than drink some more.

Comment: `var a = window.b || "foo";`.. if `b` is global variable..

Comment: @Mr_Green And if the variable is in another scope ?

Comment: @dystroy may be `this.b`.. :|

Comment: @Mr_Green You want to thing again about this one...

Comment: @Mr_Green http://jsbin.com/fubey/1/edit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is **not** a valid pattern in JavaScript. It is only valid in a context where `b` exists, for example

```
function test(b) {
    var a = b || "foo";
};
```

Comment: Damn you were faster than me!

Comment: Thank you. Makes complete sense. Unlike me!

Answer (score 12):

Your pattern is OK if the **value** of `b` is `undefined`.

If the **variable** `b` might be not defined, it's an [error](http://es5.github.io/#x15.11.6.3) to try to read it so it's a little more complicated :

```
a = typeof b!=="undefined" ? b : "foo";
```

Be careful with `b||something` even when you know the variable is defined (which is the most common case) : Most often you want to provide a default value to replace `undefined`, not prevent the caller to pass `0` or `""` so it's usually safer to do `b!==undefined ? b : "foo"`.

Comment: My votes exhausted, otherwise I would have upvoted this only :(

Comment: @thefourtheye Guess, who will do it then?

Comment: @dystroy You can only upvote /downvote 40 times a day, I guess.

Comment: @dystroy Do I smell sarcasm? ;-)

Comment: @thefourtheye No, I was only mocking myself for still not knowing that. But I don't get the votes on answers here :\

Comment: @dystroy Actually that's not exactly what OP's code is supposed to do: `a = typeof b!=="undefined" ? b || "foo" : "foo";`

Comment: @freakish To get the desired behavior, not exactly. But you point a valid thing. Edited.

Comment: @dystroy Well, that depends on what "desired" means. :) I thought that he only cares about the value being truthy/falsy? Besides, isn't `typeof undefined === "undefined"`? I mean the second condition does not seem to be necessary.

Comment: @dystroy There, +1 :-)